# Can I use eth.subscribe for incoming transactions tracking?

Tags: parity

In Parity docs I see the following description of `eth_subscribe`:

```
Starts a subscription (on WebSockets / IPC / TCP transports) to a particular event. 
For every event that matches the subscription a JSON-RPC notification
with event details and subscription ID will be sent to a client.
```

Is there any way to use it for tracking transactions coming to my wallet - considering that sender doesn't has any Smart Contract features in his wallet?